# Calculate end time of a job in SQL knowing job start time, time of pauses and job duration in minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-arithmetic

I need to calculate a job end time based on start-time, job duration in minutes, pauses data and holidays.

For example I have a table [Jobs]

```
| Job ID |    Job_Start     | Job_duration | **Job_end_time** |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|    1   | 2020-03-26 15:00 |     360      |       ?????      |
```

And I have a table [Pauses]

```
| Pause_type | Start_time | End_time |
--------------------------------------
|  Pause 1   |    10:15   |  10:30   | 
|   Lunch    |    12:00   |  12:30   | 
|  Pause 2   |    15:15   |  15:30   |
```

Workday always starts at 8:00 and ends at 17:00, but in future there could be two shifts so it will be good to make it flexible, for example write down in separate table.

Weekends and holidays ain't working days and can be added to a separate table [Holidays]

```
| Holiday_type |      Date       | 
----------------------------------
|   Weekend    |    2020-03-28   |  
|   Holiday    |    2020-04-10   |
```

Hope you can help me to solve that case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which actual _database_ are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, etc.)?

Comment: He @Denis, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please include [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you have tried already.

Comment: I'm using MS SQL. I don't have any code yet, just have a source data described above.